# How to make the search icon permanently visible in the column in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I want to make the filter icon visible permanently in the Ag-grid. The current behaviour is such that the filter icons in the columns only become visible when I hover across the column headings .

This is an example of the column definition that I am using.

```
this.ColumnDefs=[{"headerName":"Interface","field":"interfaceName",sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null'],width:120,cellStyle:{'text-align': "left"},unSortIcon: true},
{"headerName":"Status","field":"status",sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null'],width:120,cellStyle:{'text-align': "left"},unSortIcon: true},
{"headerName":"Runtime","field":"lastDate",sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null'],width:150,cellStyle:{'text-align': "left"},unSortIcon: true}]
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: yes i am still facing this issue...@wentjun

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct answer is here to set `suppressMenuHide` in `gridOptions` or directly on HTML `[suppressMenuHide]="true"`

> [**suppressMenuHide**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/) Set to true to always show the column menu button, rather than only showing when the mouse is over the column header.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it with just a small CSS. No need to consider `ColDef`.

Have a look at the plunk I've created: **[Built-In Filters Icon - show by default](https://plnkr.co/edit/gSSsVKwxS6EDJAkX4B29?p=preview)**

```
.ag-header-icon.ag-header-cell-menu-button {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: @AshutoshKumar actually, it is only the hack, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55458888/4483102)

Comment: @un.spike agree. I would anyways keep this answer in case anybody would get help from this css trick.

Comment: @Paritosh for sure np.